# How do I stop my game from Skipping Screens?

Tags: xna, c#

I used the code from this - http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml (The second method using enumerations)

I modified it to add a 3rd screen for gameplay and it functioned like the previous screen. The issue is that since the Controller Detect Screen and Title Screen both use the A button to advance. Because of this, it advances through both at the same time, going straight to the gameplay screen. I changed the code (as seen below) so that the Title Screen uses a different button. However, I want to have it so it uses the same button, but not advance at the same time.

Hopefully I explained it correctly.

```
        private void UpdateControllerDetectScreen()
    {

        //Poll all the gamepads (and the keyboard) to check to see

        //which controller will be the player one controller

        for (int aPlayer = 0; aPlayer < 4; aPlayer++)
        {

            if (GamePad.GetState((PlayerIndex)aPlayer).Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A) == true)
            {

                mPlayerOne = (PlayerIndex)aPlayer;

                mCurrentScreen = ScreenState.Title;

                return;

            }

        }

    }

    private void UpdateTitleScreen()
    {

        //Move back to the Controller detect screen if the player moves

        //back (using B) from the Title screen (this is typical game behavior

        //and is used to switch to a new player one controller)

        if (GamePad.GetState(mPlayerOne).Buttons.B == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.B) == true)
        {

            mCurrentScreen = ScreenState.ControllerDetect;

            return;

        }

        if (GamePad.GetState((PlayerIndex)mPlayerOne).Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.C) == true)
        {



            mCurrentScreen = ScreenState.GamePlay;

            return;

        }

    }

    private void UpdateGamePlayScreen()
    {

        //Move back to the Controller detect screen if the player moves

        //back (using B) from the Title screen (this is typical game behavior

        //and is used to switch to a new player one controller)

        if (GamePad.GetState(mPlayerOne).Buttons.B == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.B) == true)
        {

            mCurrentScreen = ScreenState.Title;

            return;

        }





    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to distinguish between a **single key press** (or button) from **the key being held down**.

This can be accomplished by adding an extra check to your if statement, so that besides checking if the button (or key) is *currently* down you also need to check if that same button (or key) *was* up on the previous frame.

If *both* are true, then we're dealing with with the first frame of a key press, and anything you put inside will only be triggered once. In order for it to be triggered again, you would need to *release* the button and press it again.

I've already written twice about this problem:

- [How can I stop looking for keyboard input for a length of time?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/21766/11686)
- [Global keyboard states](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26614/11686)

But transcribing the most essential bits, the technique can be summarized as this:

```
private KeyboardState _currentKeyboardState;
private KeyboardState _previousKeyboardState;

public void Update(GameTime elapsed)
{
    // Before handling input
    _currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    if(_currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) &&
       _previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.A))
    {
        // Change screen here
    }

    _previousKeyboardState = _currentKeyboardState;
}
```

Adapt this to your needs, i.e. store the gamepad state and check for it too, possibly encapsulate everything in a class (for example, the first question I linked above has an answer with an implementation that seems pretty complete, while the second question has a minimalistic implementation).

Comment: +1 For this reason you normally have an object of some kind that helps you work with the keyboard. I have a `KeyboardDevice` which has these methods: `IsKeyDown`, `IsKeyUp`, `WasKeyPressed`, `WasKeyReleased` - all of which take a key and return whether what I'm asking it is happening with that key.

Comment: Thanks. Your Global Keyboard States example worked, though there was a grammar error where _currentKeyboardState;
 was spelled as _currentKeybordState;